# std::vector as template parameter... all hell breaks lose

Tags: c++

I'm exploding soon... Someone please point out what is wrong in here currently:

```
template <typename TType, template <typename ...> class Container, class Comparer>
Container<TType>* sort(const Container<TType>& container) {
    ...
}
```

The problem comes when I try to call this function with std::vector as its Container parameter. I get the following errors:

```
main.cpp:24:34: error: no matching function for call to 'func()'
main.cpp:24:34: note: candidate is:
main.cpp:14:6: note: template<class T, template<class ...> class Container> void func()
main.cpp:14:6: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
```

And here's how I'm trying to call it:

```
std::vector<int>* m(sort<int, std::vector<int>, Comparer>(m));
```

When I remove the template template parameter from the function it works, but not with it... I'm using the latest g++ compiler that comes with MinGW. The IDE is NetBeans 7.3 tho that shouldn't affect much. Compiler arguments are:

```
-std=c++11 -Wall -pedantic
```

Thanks for every help,
 - Joey

Comment: Nah... anything less than 300 lines of errors can't really be considered "all hell breaks loose" for a C++ program with templates. :)

Comment: Why are you showing us the `sort` function when the error is clearly about the `func` function?

Comment: *The latest g++ compiler that comes with MinGW* is a horribly bad description of a compiler. Even today I would have to lookup what that means in the mingw distribution. A few months from now someone looking at the question will have to find out and actually cared would have to look what *current* meant today...

Comment: from this question: if you want to pass std::vector (or any other container type) as a template argument, syntax is: template<template <typename ...> class Container = std::vector>class ResourceManager

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You're supposed to provide a template, not a specific type created from a template.  The correct call would be:

```
sort<int, std::vector, Comparer>(m)
```

Note that `sort` itself is providing the template arguments for `Container`, as in `const Container<TType>&`.  Clearly setting `Container` to `std::vector<int>` makes no sense; you'd be asking the compiler to do something like `std::vector<int><int>`

Comment: ah right... okay I should just get some sleep I guess. Thank you for pointing that out.